# How to reach variable from viewcontroller in a custom class?

Tags: swift, xcode, class, realitykit

I need to append something to my anchor.
I am trying to do this in a function of my class, but i declared this anchor in my viewcontroller.

This anchor is not recognized in my class. How do I reach this anchor?

**viewController.swift:**

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit
import Combine

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let gameAnchor = AnchorEntity(plane: .horizontal)
        arView.scene.addAnchor(gameAnchor)

        //generate random width en distance
        let randomDistance = Double.random(in: 0.07...0.25)
        let randomWidth = Double.random(in: 0.01...0.05)

        //make a new platform
        let newPlatform = Platform(width: randomWidth, heigth: 0.1, depth: 0.05, distance: randomDistance)
        newPlatform.makePlatform()
    }
}
```

**My class:**

```
import Foundation
import RealityKit

class Platform {
    var width: Double = 0.05
    var heigth: Double = 0.1
    var depth: Double = 0.05
    var distance: Double = 0.1

    init(width: Double, heigth: Double, depth: Double, distance: Double) {
        self.width = width
        self.heigth = heigth
        self.depth = depth
        self.distance = distance
    }

    func makePlatform() {
        let platformMesh = MeshResource.generateBox(width: Float(width), height: 0.1, depth: 0.05)
        let platformMaterial = SimpleMaterial(color: .red, isMetallic: false)
        let newPlatform = ModelEntity(mesh: platformMesh, materials: [platformMaterial])
        newPlatform.position.x = Float(distance)
        newPlatform.position.y = 0.05

        //append it to my anchor
        ///gameAnchor.addChild(newPlatform)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry if this was asked before, but i've been searching for 2 hours and can't find the solution for my particular situation. I will delete the question if any of you can provide a link to another question that solves my problem.

Comment: Where did you declare your AnchorEntity?

Comment: In my viewDidLoad of the main viewController

Comment: Wait so you want the platform to have the `AnchorEntity`

Comment: No, in my Platform class i have a function "makePlatform". That's where I actually make a platform and you can see something written in a comment: that's where I want to add the platform to my anchor. But the anchor is unknown there because it was declared in the main viewcontroller's viewdidload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After newPlatform.makePlatform() just add something like

```
 gameAnchor.addChild(newPlatform.platform)
```

and make the platform a class variable, not local to the makePlatform method. You also need to make newPlatform a class variable in your view controller, not local to viewDidLoad.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't actually show in my AR view when I test the app

Comment: Sorry, you also need to make newPlatform a class variable, not local to viewDidLoad. (edited answer)

Comment: Oh no, sorry this was my fault. I made platform a class variable but I forgot to delete the "let" where I declared my platform model entity in my makePlatform method. So I was just declaring a new one there. Fixed!